# VS2013/TFS2013 Query Reviewers

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs-workitem

I have been searching MSDN/Google/Stackoverflow and not able to find a way to create a query where it shows all the code reviews requesting your input. This is before you accept the code review and before you might have any knowledge of it. I know we can obtain open code review work items with a query like the following:

```
And/Or    Field              Operator        Value
Team      Project            =               @Project
And       Work Item Type     =               Code Review Request
And       State              <>              Closed
```

You can also personalize reviews you have accepted with the following:

```
And/Or    Field              Operator        Value
Team      Project            =               @Project
And       Work Item Type     =               Code Review Request
And       State              <>              Closed
And       Accepted By        Contains        @Me
```

These solution are not exactly what I am looking for, as I am trying to find a query that uses the @Me Value to find all reviews before you accept. This is to help anyone see all their pending reviews requests if in case they miss or deleted the email alert for the code review request. Any ideas, suggestion, and solutions are greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Assigned To`

```
AndOr   Field   Operator                        Value
                Work Item Type      In Group    Microsoft.CodeReviewResponseCategory
And             Assigned To         <>          @Me
And             Accepted By         =
```

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly other than the 'AND Assigned To = @ Me' in the work item table needed to be 'AND Assigned To <> @ Me' for what I was requiring. Cheers to you mate!